# Can I create a generalized vm image with RDP disabled

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, rdp, hardening

How can we create windows VM image with RDP disabled for VMs created from that image? I want publish an RDP hardened image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a [Custom Script Extension for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows)

Create a PowerShell scripts which disables RDP and reference it:

```
{
  "fileUris": ["https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/privatecontainer/script1.ps1"],
  "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe script1.ps1",
  "managedIdentity" : {}
}
```

Powershell script to disable RDP in registry:

```
Invoke-Command –Computername "customname" –ScriptBlock {Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name "fDenyTSConnections" –Value 1}
```

Comment: Great thanks for that. Can we not create a generalized image which has RDP already disabled?
The prob is the I want to publish this image and my org can create VMs off it. They might necessarily run the script, so I want to create image which has the RDP disabled.